# How can I merge two arrays into a dictionary?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have 2 arrays:

```
    var identic = [String]()
    var linef = [String]()
```

I've appended them with data. Now for usability purposes my goal is to combine them all into a dictionary with the following structure

```
FullStack = ["identic 1st value":"linef first value", "identic 2nd value":"linef 2nd value"]
```

I've been browsing around the net and couldnt find a viable solution to this.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: it's all about **zip**, which does this for you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `enumerated()`:

```
var arrayOne: [String] = []
var arrayTwo: [String] = []

var dictionary: [String: String] = [:]

for (index, element) in arrayOne.enumerated() {
    dictionary[element] = arrayTwo[index]
}
```

The **pro** approach would be to use an extension:

```
extension Dictionary {
    public init(keys: [Key], values: [Value]) {
        precondition(keys.count == values.count)

        self.init()

        for (index, key) in keys.enumerate() {
            self[key] = values[index]
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** `enumerate()` → `enumerated()` (Swift 3 → Swift 4)

Comment: I added this extension to my project, but I'm not seeing the initializer when I try to initialize a dictionary with this. Could you add example usage?

Comment: in a sense, this answer is not, really, correct - you just use **zip** to do exactly this.

Answer (score 58):

Starting with Xcode 9.0, you can simply do:

```
var identic = [String]()
var linef = [String]()

// Add data...

let fullStack = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(identic, linef))
```

If your keys are not guaranteed to be unique, use this instead:

```
let fullStack =
    Dictionary(zip(identic, linef), uniquingKeysWith: { (first, _) in first })
```

or

```
let fullStack =
    Dictionary(zip(identic, linef), uniquingKeysWith: { (_, last) in last })
```

Documentation:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/init(uniquekeyswithvalues:)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/init(_:uniquingkeyswith:)

Comment: old links seem to be broken. new link : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init

Answer (score 23):

A slightly different method, which doesn't require the arrays to be of the same length, because the `zip` function will safely handle that.

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(keys: [Key], values: [Value]) {
        self.init()

        for (key, value) in zip(keys, values) {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output when the arrays are of different lengths?

Comment: It only zips the contents up to the length of the shortest array.

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to be safer and ensure you're picking the smaller array count each time (so that you're not potentially crashing if the second array is smaller than the first), then do something like:

```
var identic = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
var linef = ["1", "2", "3"]

var Fullstack = [String: String]()
for i in 0..<min(linef.count, identic.count) {
    Fullstack[identic[i]] = linef[i]
}

print(Fullstack) // "[A: 1, B: 2, C: 3]"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic solution

```
func dictionaryFromKeysAndValues<K : Hashable, V>(keys:[K], values:[V]) -> Dictionary<K, V>
{
  assert((count(keys) == count(values)), "number of elements odd")
  var result = Dictionary<K, V>()
  for i in 0..<count(keys) {
    result[keys[i]] = values[i]
  }
  return result
}

var identic = ["identic 1st value", "identic 2nd value", "identic 3rd value"]
var linef = ["linef 1st value", "linef 2nd value", "linef 3rd value"]

let mergedDictionary = dictionaryFromKeysAndValues(identic, linef)
```

Comment: It's not the same, I'm not using enumerate() and mine is a generic solution which is not restricted to strings.

Comment: Mine is a generic solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a extension that combines some of the previous answers and accepts all Sequences, not only Arrays.

```
public extension Dictionary {
    init<K: Sequence, V: Sequence>(keys: K, values: V) where K.Element == Key, V.Element == Value, K.Element: Hashable {
        self.init()
        for (key, value) in zip(keys, values) {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

That extension doesn't require the sequences to be the same lengths. If you want that, here is an extension with assertions.

```
public extension Dictionary {
    init<K: Sequence, V: Sequence>(keys: K, values: V) where K.Element == Key, V.Element == Value, K.Element: Hashable {
        self.init()
        var keyIterator = keys.makeIterator()
        for value in values {
            let key = keyIterator.next()
            assert(key != nil, "The value sequence was longer.")
            self[key!] = value
        }
        assert(keyIterator.next() == nil, "The key sequence was longer.")
    }
}
```